# Cakephp Problem implementing access control lists

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, acl

I am trying implement a simple ACL controlled application. I just read up all the info in the cakephp website and accompanying example. I tried to implement the same on a trial website works fine. But it is very complex when creating ACOS and AROS and the table is quite something.

I want to implement a simple user, moderator and admin control list in application. I have my app running with both cakephp 1.2.9 and 1.3.6. Is there simpler alternative to achieve this.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Persevere! It's not a trivial component, but it is *very* useful.
I found this helpful: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple way of managing the permissions, you may try the following plugin: http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl

Regards